# SublimeREPL: MATLAB displaying inconsistent output for structures (macOS)

Tags: macos, matlab, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

sublimeREPL: MATLAB seems appropriately configured, and will display output for matrices, tables, or even [1x1] structures.

When I try to display the output for any structure larger than [1x1], however, I just get an inexplicable white block to the left of the `>>` prompt, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y9sS.png) (sorry for the imgur link, I don't have enough rep for an inline image).

Any idea why that would be the case, or what I can do to fix it? I've used SublimeREPL: MATLAB on several similar systems without this glitch, but I can't for the life of me figure out what is different about my current setup that might lead to such an error.

Thanks much!

system specs:
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
MATLAB R2017a (8.2.0.538062)
Sublime Text Version 3.0, Build 3143
[SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I had auto-indent set to "true" in my User settings.

Changing them as follows eliminates the problem:

```
// standard sublime view settings that will be overwritten on each repl view
// this has to be customized as a whole dictionary
"repl_view_settings": {
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "auto_indent": false,
    "smart_indent": false,
    "spell_check": false,
    "indent_subsequent_lines": false,
    "detect_indentation": false,
    "auto_complete": true,
    "line_numbers": false,
    "gutter": true
}
```